# Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) Django how to solve?WITH MY CODE

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-csrf

when i press button, this error is blow up

> Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /orders/basket_adding/

/

> I take csrf_token from the form on the main page, all the others
>   inherit from the page where the form is, from where I get the token!

Pls help me)

views

```
def basket_adding(request):
    print('HER')
    return_dict                             = {}
    session_key                             = request.session.session_key
    data                                    = request.POST
    context = {}
    return JsonResponse(return_dict)
```

/////

/////
html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="single">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="single-main">
            <div class="single-top-main">
                <div class="col-md-5 single-top">   
                   <div class="flexslider">
                      <ul class="slides">
                        {% for img in images %}
                        <li data-thumb="{{ img.image.url }}">
                            <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="{{ img.image.url }}" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                        </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 single-top-left simpleCart_shelfItem">
                    <h2>{{ product_himself.brand.name_of_brand }}</h2>
                    <h1 class="product_name" action="{% url 'orders:basket_adding' %}" >{{ product_himself.name_of_product }}</h1>
                    <p class="hidden product_id">{{  product_himself.id }}</p>
                    {% if product_himself.discount %}
                        <span>$<strike>{{ product_himself.price_of_product }}</strike>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="item_price">{{ product_himself.price_with_discount }}</span></span>
                    {% else %}
                        $<h6 class="item_price">{{ product_himself.price_of_product }}</h6>
                    {% endif %}         
                    <p>{{ product_himself.description }}</p>
                    <h4>Size</h4>
                    <ul class="bann-btns">
                        <li><select class="bann-size">
                            <option value="s">Small</option>
                            <option value="m">Medium</option>
                            <option value="l">Large</option>
                        </select>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="item_add">Add To Cart</a></li>                   
                    </ul>
                </div>
               <div class="clearfix"> </div>
           </div>
           <div class="singlepage-product">
                {% for smart in img_bran %}
                 <div class="col-md-3 home-grid">
                        <div class="home-product-main">
                           <div class="home-product-top">
                              <a href="#"><img src="{{ smart.image.url }}" alt="" class="img-responsive zoom-img"></a>
                           </div>
                            <div class="home-product-bottom">
                                    <h3><a href="{{ smart.access_to_product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ smart.access_to_product.description|truncatechars:25 }}</a></h3>
                                    <p>Explore Now</p>                      
                            </div>
                            <div class="srch">
                                <span>${{ smart.access_to_product.price_of_product }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                {% endfor %}
              <div class="clearfix"> </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

base html (where located form, from which i take csrf_token)

```
<div class="hidden">
    <form class="default_form"></form>{% csrf_token %}
</div>
```

////

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.item_add', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        product_id          = $(".product_id").html();
        product_name        = $(".product_name").html();
        product_price       = parseFloat($(".item_price").html())   
        product_size        = $(".bann-size").val();
        url                 = $(".product_name").attr("action");
        console.log(url)
        var data            = {};
        var csrf_token      = $('.default_form [name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
        data.product_id     = product_id
        data.product_name   = product_name
        data.product_price  = product_price
        data.product_size   = product_size
        data["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = csrf_token;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: true,
            success: function(data){
                console.log("OK");


            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data + "ERROR")
                alert("Something wrong, try again!")
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you have not inserted CSRF token in form tag so it will not get any CSRF token.

for example

```
<div class="hidden">
     <form class="default_form">
           {% csrf_token %}
     </form>
</div>
```